# Allocating a fixed sized object to a pointer (pointing to a struct) without using malloc

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, structure

I have a pointer to a struct `list* ptr`
The struct contains a char and a pointer to the next struct and these are used for an array of structures like so:

```
list array[setSize]; //setSize is defined as 20
```

Without using malloc, I need to initialize `list* ptr` so that it has all the elements of the array.

I have tried the following and I get a segmentation fault.  I believe I am utterly misunderstanding how pointers work. (I haven't touched C in a long while)

```
int j = 0;
ptr = sizeof(array[j]);  //i was thinking this would allocate space     
for(j; j < setSize; j++)
    array[j].next = array[j+1].next;
ptr = array; //i thought this would point to the beginning of the array
```

I have looked at a lot of sites about C and linked list.  I had books but they don't give enough detail about this particular use of pointers or structures. I have been trying this for a while but I am sure I am missing something.

I just need to understand where I am going wrong and what direction to head towards.

Thanks for any and all help.

**Below is a Re-post with more code:**

```
//this should initialize array so that ptr contains all array elements
void initialize ( list array[] ) { 
int j;
for(j = 0; j < setSize - 1; j++){
array[j].next = array[j+1].next;  //using the & does not seem to work, so I don't use it
array[j].next = NULL;
}
ptr = &(array[0]);
}
```

Later on I am using this in my own malloc function (which is where the seg fault happens)

```
//this should allocate a new list cell in array
list* my_malloc () { 
list* temp; 
temp = ptr; 
if(ptr = 0) {printf("Empty!\n");  return;}
else{ //the next line creates the seg fault
ptr = (*ptr).next; 
}
return temp;
}

list* cell ( char n, list* next ) {
  list* x = my_malloc(); 
  x->value = n;
  return x;
  x->next = next;
  return x;
}

main ( void* argv, int argc ) {
  initialize(array);
  list* x = nil;
  char ch = a;
  int i;
  for ( i = 0; i < setSize; i++ )
    x = cell(ch,x); 
  for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    list* y = x->next;
    my_free(x);  //this is my own free function 
    x = y;
  };
  for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    x = cell(ch,x);
}
```

Comment: considering how many bugs are in the above code, I think it would be wise to include the definition of `buffer` and your struct.

Comment: For the future, it's useful to cut down your code to a minimal but complete program that exhibits your problem. That way we can compile it and run it and see the exact error you're seeing without having to infer anything.

Comment: This is the first time I see somebody creating the list this way. Read here for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list. The base idea of the list that you can add and remove items from the list without copying data, which you should do in the case of arrays. And `list *root` is enough for all operations on the list. But you'll have to use malloc. You can also find a lot of interesting information in the following book: http://www.algorist.com/

Comment: @Elalfer: you may want to look at slides 20-21 here: http://www.arcos.inf.uc3m.es/~jdaniel/sem-cpp-11/Madrid-bs.pdf

Comment: @ninjalj: I do not really understand what do you want to tell me. If `For which size of sequence is a list faster than a vector?` - I know this and I would also add that it is really depends of the size of the elements.

Comment: @Elalfer: mmm, you may want to look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html , my point being that it actually makes sense to implement a list using an array.

Comment: @ninjalj: I'm sorry I'm not 100% agree. `ArrayList` is just a `Resizable-array implementation of the List interface` which uses arrays as an internal container. This could be useful in some cases, but I do not think that `ArrayList` implementation uses `->next` pointers, which doesn't make sense in the case of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
#define ARRAY_LENGTH (20)

struct list
{
    char ch;
    struct list* next;
};

struct list array[ARRAY_LENGTH];   // array's memory is allocated with this, no need to use malloc
struct list* ptr = &(array[0]);    // ptr now points to the 1st item in the array
int j;                             // I'm declaring 'j' outside of the for loop just in case you are using c and not c++

for(j=0 ; j < ARRAY_LENGTH-1 ; j++)
    array[j].next = &(array[j+1]); // .next of jth item in array now points to the following item

array[j].next = NULL;              // assign .next of last item to NULL, so you know when you have reached the end of the array when traversing it.
```

Note that the for-loop is executed for (ARRAY_LENGTH - 1) items, not ARRAY_LENGTH items, since array[j+1] would be out of bounds in the last iteration.

Now that you have ptr pointing to the 1st item in the array, you can traverse through it with something like:

```
struct list* curItem;  // this will be your iterator to traverse the array
curItem = ptr;         // initialize your iterator to point to the 1st item
while(curItem != NULL) // note that with this, you don't need to know the length of the array
{
    printf("Current item's .ch is %c\r\n", curItem->ch); // don't forget to include the header for printf
    curItem = curItem->next;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I believe that perhaps this will solve my problem. In addition, when I want to traverse through the list using the pointer, shouldn't I be able to access the character or the pointer within the struct ?  And if so, how?

Comment: I edited my actual code using your solution and was given "incompatible assignment type" error so I will keep my original for loop. The seg fault I get is when I try (later on in the code) to use the pointer rather than the array.  I am trying to use the pointer to put elements in the array. In order to add a struct to the array, I have to use the pointer to do so - it is supposed to be a linked list and I remove a link to put into the array.

Comment: Hi, it was the ptr = array, changing it to ptr = &(array[0]) should make it fine, it compiles here.

Comment: Yes it does compile - thank you.  I will make those changes on here as well.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Everything you have there is pretty close to making sense except for this line:

```
ptr = sizeOf(buffer[j]);
```

I presume you mean `sizeof` there?  At any rate, that operation is meaningless (and illegal, since you're trying to assign an integer to a variable of pointer type).  You don't need to allocate any memory, your definition of `array` already does that.

You do have a problem with your `for` loop - you're going go one past the end of the array, which might be what's causing your segmentation fault.  It's either that or the fact that you didn't initialize `j`, so it could be accessing some memory it shouldn't.  I think you probably want something like:

```
for (j = 0; j < setSize - 1; j++) 
{
    array[j].next = &array[j+1];
}
```

Edit:  The reason for your segfault is that this line:

```
if(ptr = 0) {printf("Empty!\n");  return;}
```

**Sets** `ptr` to `0`.  I think you want a `==` there.  Another point - you say "using the `&` does not seem to work, so I don't use it".  That probably means your `list` structure is declared incorrectly, or at least in a pretty nonstandard way.  You should probably show more of your program - it seems like you have some pretty fundamental misunderstandings of how pointers work.

Comment: +1: He wants `ptr = &array[0];` but you get the nod over the other answers for spotting the overrun.  You should probably ensure that `array[setSize-1].next = 0;`, too.

Comment: @Jonathan, he has `ptr = array;` there already - that's exactly the same, isn't it?

Comment: ptr = sizeof(array[j])  is what is it supposed to be.  it was a typo. but i have changed the for loop and still get a fault.

Comment: I have changed my question to include more code.  Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: @newg - you still haven't shown enough code, but I see the reason for your segmentation fault now.

Comment: @Carl Norum - I have made that change to my actual code and yes it stops the seg fault Thank you! I was afraid that posting my entire program would be too much but I will put in more code.

Comment: @newg - you don't necessarily have to post all of it - but a complete program that shows your problem is always helpful.

Comment: @Carl: I didn't notice the '`ptr = array;` assignment after the loop; I'm not sure if it was added or not.  Yes, that is equivalent to `ptr = &array[0];` - and that assignment can before or after the loop.  The 'before loop' assignment of `sizeof(...)` is bogus.

Comment: I have added more code and the segmentation fault comes back after using the x = cell(ch, x) in the for loop in main. During the first loop, ptr is empty (ptr == 0) is true, so it returns to main and then loops again, but this results in fault.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` doesn't allocate space. If you don't want to use malloc, you have to allocate your space either on the stack or wherever globals are stored (probably bss). Since you presumably do that with your array definition, `ptr = &buffer[j]` will get you a pointer to the `j`th element of the buffer. I think you meant "addressof" instead of "sizeof", which is spelled `&` in C. Of course, `buffer` isn't `array`. That's either a typo or something very wrong.

Anyway, your code is a bit misordered. What you probably wanted to do was initialize your pointer to `array`, then iterate through the elements, setting next:

```
ptr = array;
for (j = 0; j < setSize; j++)
    array[j].next = &array[j+1];
array[setSize - 1] = NULL; // The last element was set to a lie.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array[j].next = array[j+1].next;
```

That won't work since array[j+1].next isn't defined.  Depending on how `buffer[i].next` is defined, you should be able to do this:

```
array[j].next = &array[j+1];
```